# How exactly does healpy's anafast compute the angular power spectrum?

Tags: healpy

I'm trying to understand why randomly dropping half of my data makes the Cls lower. I couldn't find it on the healpix documentation or google.

[Angular power spectrum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFX5I.png)

EDIT: I've never worked with anything like this before. The data I have covers 1/4 of the whole sphere with redshifts between 0.69 and 1.3 with halos of masses between log10M = 13 and log10M = 15. I have the angular position, redshift, mass and number of particles. 
I filled a map with zeroes, and added the number of particles at their position on the map. Is that the correct approach, and does anafast consider that and computes the correct Cls for a partial map?

Answer (score 1):

Spherical harmonics transforms in HEALPix are always on the full sky,                                                             if the map is masked, those pixels are set to 0. It is recommended to                                                            remove monopole from the map before running `anafast` to reduce                                                                  boundary effects.

I added this text to the docstring of anafast.

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing that out. But I still don't understand why this is happening. Does anafast just sums up the angular power spectra of every combination of two points in my map, without any normalization? Do I need the same amount of data points in different redshift bins if I want to compare them?

Comment: Easiest is to make a union mask  and compare them with same sky coverage. Otherwise you can at least correct for the sky fraction. You have to divide the spectrum by the sky fraction or its square, I don't remember.

Comment: Not sure how much my problem is related to the mask: when I use anafast to extract the Cl's from Planck 2018 data map, (wget -O COM_CMB_IQU-commander_2048_R3.00_full "https://pla.esac.esa.int/pla-sl/data-action?MAP.MAP_OID=13470") I got a Cl that's about six times larger than the CL released by Planck 2018. Are there any pitfalls that I should be aware of that might have caused this mismatch?